# How to automatically get the password while doing git clone in bash

Tags: bash, automation

My bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone https://abc@xyz.com/xxx/xxxx/pqr.git
git clone https://abc@xyz.com/xxx/xxxx/pqr2.git
git clone https://abc@xyz.com/xxx/xxxx/pqr3.git
git clone https://abc@xyz.com/xxx/xxxx/pqr4.git
```

Now it asks me the password every time .,ie 4 times....and I have to enter the password 4 times .,ie each time it does the git clone.
I want to store the password in a variable say 'passwd' and use it to give as a input the the **"Enter password"** statement. Basically need to **automate** it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be git credential. Just set the timeout to a large enough value to clone those repositories:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600' # 1 hour
```

But if you really want to do it the way you described, then monitor the output of a command with [expect](/questions/tagged/expect) and send the password with `exp_send "passwd\r"` when `Enter password` is encountered.

Comment: I want a scripting solution as my problem is not exactly of git.....its sort of similar

Comment: @Shubham : Look at [tag:expect] then